# ResponseNotReady exception in python httplib2

Tags: python

In a python thread I execute following statement:

```
(response, content) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'POST', body=data, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/rdf+xml' })
```

Most of the time it succeeds. But intermittently I am hitting following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataStoreManager.py", line 31, in loadData
    (response, content) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'POST', body=data, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/rdf+xml' })
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1022, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
```

If its relevant, I try to connect to an EC2 instance in us east zone from a laptop in west zone

What is wrong?

I have 20 threads (which all seem to work fine most of time) and each thread executes following code;

```
(response, content) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'POST', body=data, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/rdf+xml' })
print "Response %s" % response.status
```

Comment: The nature of the internet. Sometimes the thing you are trying to POST to just won't be there. Try to design your program to just try again if that happens.

Comment: I already do that but was not sure the cause of this issue

Comment: Just fickleness sadly.